# PHP & MySQL: Good/efficient of showing statistics from thousands of rows on each page load

Tags: php, mysql

I know this is the wrong way to go about it, but I have a database filled with stats about vehicles that are imported from excel files.

For each vehicle(about 100 currently, updated each three days) I have from 500 to 2000 rows of data which is used to build graphs regarding fuel consumption, distance driven etc..
This is fairly simple and it takes from 1 to 3 seconds to load, but I also need the total stats and compare it against each car.

So if I build the graph for car id 1, I want to see the difference between its fuel consumption and the global fuel consumption (of all existing cars).

Is there a way of doing this without querying not only the single car but also all cars on each page load ?

Thank you

Comment: I don't see how that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to pre-compile your stats into a summary table. Write a function that takes in 1 vehicle as a parameter, compiles all your stats, then saves them to a dedicated summary table. Then write a background script that calls that function for all vehicles one by one. You can call the background script as often as you feel the stats need to be updated, leaving the web interface free to do very little computing/io.

This type of thing has saved me quite a big of headache over the years.

Comment: Thank you, I thought about this and maybe it's the best solution, the only downside is that I would have to personally visit that page each day because I don't want the client to do it and wait each time. He insists he needs "quick" stats.

Comment: I wouldn't use a page-load to compile the summary table. That's what the background job is supposed to do.

Comment: @C.Ovidiu - what stops you from using events or triggers to perform computation and update a simple summary table? Why would anyone have to visit anything in order to have their RDBMS perform its job for them? It's not 1999 anymore, in 2016 you have events, triggers, stored procedures. Heck, you can even invoke system commands if you want to.

Comment: @N.B.I know what you are saying, but on shared hosting that's only so much you can do. Thank you anyway